# PHP how to add slashes into array

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, addslashes

i have a problem i want to add slashes at the starting and the end of each string of my array.

This is an example of my actual array :

```
$patte = array();
$patte[0] = "httpd";
$patte[1] = "vsftpd";
$patte[2] = 'gohphp';
$patte[3] = 'abcdef';
```

i use this array for taking information into a DataBase so i can't place slashes now, or this is going to not working.

(mysql_query ... while mysql_fetch_array ...)

I need to rename these entry.
For this i use a second array, and with the command : "preg_replace" i can translate every strings like i want.
But preg_replace want me to add slashes in $patte

I want to obtain an array like this

```
$pattes = array();
$pattes[0] = "/httpd/";
$pattes[1] = "/vsftpd/";
$pattes[2] = '/gohphp/';
$pattes[3] = '/abcdef/';
```

Can you help me please.
I'm gonna have like 1000 line into this array.

Comment: Consider using `array_map`

Comment: taking array from sql or generating it from php only?

Comment: only generated from php, i have not the permission to create table sql :/

Comment: worths mentioning that if the input data is untrusted one should also use `preg_quote` http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [**array_map()**](http://www.php.net/array_map) you can apply callback to every element of your array :

```
function addSlashes($str)
{
    return "/".$str."/";
}
$newArray = array_map("addSlashes", $patte);//array with the new values
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map):

```
$pattes = array_map(function($str) {
  return '/'.$str.'/';
}, $pattes);
```